# How to make sure the StreamedResponse chunk is a whole string

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-http

My server emits a Server-side Event of json data. Now during the 'loading' period, the payload is short, but when the stream is completed I get a Format exception because the payload exceeds the content-length of the chunk.

Is there a way to ensure that the chunk is a full string before the

```dart
final imageEventProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<Map<String, dynamic>>(
  (ref) async* {
    final request = http.Request(
      'POST',
      backendUrl().replace(
        pathSegments: ['gen-image'],
      ),
    );

    final auth = ref.read(authProvider);

    request.body = jsonEncode({'prompt': 'a desert landscape'});
    request.headers["Accept"] = "text/event-stream";
    request.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
    request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    request.headers['X-FIREBASE-TOKEN'] = await auth.currentUser!.getIdToken();

    final sResp = await request.send();

    final predictionStream = sResp.stream.transform(utf8.decoder);

    await for (final part in predictionStream) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(part);
      if (data['status'] != 'succeeded') {
        ref.state = const AsyncLoading();
      }

      yield data;
    }
  },
);
```

I want to make sure the chuck is full string before passing it off to jsonDecode. Would that be possible?

### Edit

#### Server Side

The model for the event in the python server:

```python
@dataclass
class SSEvent:
    message: dict[str, Any]

    def encode(self) -> bytes:
        return json.dumps(self.message).encode("utf-8")
```

And how the response is structured.

```python
async def sse():
        pred_resp = await client.post(
            url,
            json={"version": version, "input": input},
            headers=headers,
        )
        data = pred_resp.json()
        pred_url = "{}/{}".format(url, data["id"])
        while data["status"] != "succeeded":
            pred_resp = await client.post(pred_url, headers=headers)
            data = pred_resp.json()
            event = SSEvent({"status": "loading"})
            yield event.encode()
        else:
            data = pred_resp.json()
            event = SSEvent(
                {
                    **data,
                }
            )
            yield event.encode()

    response = await make_response(
        sse(),
        {
            "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        },
    )
```

#### Client side

As per suggestions by @pskink I have changed the provider. But the FormatExceptions persists

```dart
final imageEventProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<Map<String, dynamic>>(
  (ref) async* {
    final request = http.Request(
      'POST',
      backendUrl().replace(
        pathSegments: ['gen-image'],
      ),
    );

    final auth = ref.read(authProvider);

    request.body = jsonEncode({'prompt': 'a desert landscape'});
    request.headers["Accept"] = "text/event-stream";
    request.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
    request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    request.headers['X-FIREBASE-TOKEN'] = await auth.currentUser!.getIdToken();

    final sResp = await request.send();

    final predictionStream = sResp.stream.transform(json.fuse(utf8).decoder);

    final data = await predictionStream.single as Map<String, dynamic>;

    if (data!['status'] != 'succeeded') {
      ref.state = AsyncLoading();
    }
    yield data;
  },
);
```

I still get a FormatException.

Comment: instead of `sResp.stream.transform(utf8.decoder)` do `sResp.stream.transform(jdon.fuse(utf8).decoder)` - for more on `fuse` refer to https://dart.dev/articles/archive/converters-and-codecs

Comment: of course it should be `json.fuse(....`, and not `jdon`

Comment: @pskink now I get this error, and the request stops: `FormatException: Unexpected character (at offset 0)`

Comment: and did you call `final data = await predictionStream.single`instead of whole `await for ...` ?

Comment: @pskink I get the same error either way.

Comment: so your response seems to be not a valid JSON data - I run it with minimal `{}` JSON map and it works ok

Comment: @pskink It is valid data. I have added the server side code. All messages from the vendor api are converted to JSON code before utf-8 encoding.

Comment: @pskink that has been my issue. How do I detect if the chunk is a complete json string. The size of the data would be variable. Sometimes it will be and some time it wont, so this issue will persists. I have though about going into a infinite try catch blocks but that would be an overkill.

Comment: you don't have to worry about that: this is a responsibility of `json.decoder` to parse the input data: it yields the final result only when it detects the end of input data - that's why I used `await stream.single` since the resulting stream (after calling `transform` method) yields only one value - you can also use `await for ...` but you will see that this loop will execute only once